# How do I modify the array that a for loop is going through?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, iteration

I have this code:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    console.log(i)
    if (arr[i] == 4) {
        arr.push(5)
    }
}

console.log(arr)
```

Even though I am pushing 5 to the array, and the array is getting updated, the for loop is not getting the updated version of the array on every iteration. However, the following code gives the expected result. Why?

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]


for (var i of arr) {
    console.log(i)
    if (arr[i] == 4) {
        arr.push(5)
    }
}
```

Comment: in general it's considered a bad practice to modify an array (or other compound data) that you are currently looping thru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement:

> the for loop is not getting the updated version of the array on every iteration

is incorrect. The for loop iteration has full access to the array as it changes.

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  console.log('i:', i, ', arr.length:', arr.length, ', arr:', arr);
  if (arr[i] === 4) {
    arr.push(5);
  }
}
/*
'i:' 0 ', arr.length:' 4 ', arr:' [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
'i:' 1 ', arr.length:' 4 ', arr:' [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
'i:' 2 ', arr.length:' 4 ', arr:' [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
'i:' 3 ', arr.length:' 4 ', arr:' [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
'i:' 4 ', arr.length:' 5 ', arr:' [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour is all exactly as expected.

Both code snippets output 5 values to the console; the only difference being that the first snippet outputs the variable `i` while the second one outputs an element from the array. These two are `1` apart, because `i` starts at `0` and your array starts at `1`.

To get your expected output with a `for` loop, simply output an element and not the counter:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    console.log(arr[i])
    if (arr[i] == 4) {
        arr.push(5)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is happening because in the for loop, arr.length is a static object and it does not update. But what is actually happening in the for...of loop is that it is actually iterating over the items in the object, rather than executing a block of code several times. So it would make sense that it gets the variable, which is dynamic and changes.